# Multiple headsets, multiple sources, easy switching

Tags: gaming, wireless, headset

Currently we're using two old RF headphones with a two-channel switch to easily switch between our two PCs and the TV (two channels are enough since not all three devices are used at the same time). I'd like to replace that with a) higher quality transmission and b) add a microphone to replace the table-bound wired separate Mic.

My first thought was "bluetooth", especially with multipoint's claimed simple switching. But meanwhile I read that bluetooth cannot provide Stereo quality *and* use the microphone at the same time, so that's not an option. After searching some more, the most interesting options are SteelSeries' [Arctis 7](https://steelseries.com/gaming-headsets/arctis-7) (but since the transmitter requires a USB port this won't work with the TV's 3.5mm output) and the [Siberia 800](https://steelseries.com/gaming-headsets/siberia-800) or [840](https://steelseries.com/gaming-headsets/siberia-840) (basically the 800+bluetooth). Leaving the high price aside, I cannot find any information about supporting and switching between multiple transmitters. Since one PC is actually nearby the TV, one 840's transmitter can probably connected to both of these, but I'm still wondering about the second transmitter and how easily the headsets can switch to the other transmitter.

So, in summary I'm looking for the following:

- 2 (or 3) wireless headsets (i.e. including Microphones)
- 3 transmitters, one of which must use 3.5mm
- easy switching between the transmitter
- optionally bluetooth, and preferably more modern than RF though the simple two-channel switch had its benefits

Comment: What's your budget like? What are you using these for?

Comment: @JMY1000 I spent a mere 100 EUR for the three RF headphones+transmitters, now I'm willing to spend a bit more, though I'd seriously like to avoid three times the ~350 EUR each Siberia would cost... Usage would include gaming, listening to music, watching movies and voice chat (mostly non-parallel )

Comment: Hm, a second option might be headphones (maybe bluetooth with multipoint, though the TV would still need a transmitter), and separate (bluetooth?) microphone that's still comfortable together with the headphones...